# Does rails have a built in method for converting database.yml config into database URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a standard postgresql database.yml config. I need to generate a database URL to be used elsewhere with the same parameters. I would think rails had a method for that or?

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  pool: 10
  reaping_frequency: 10
  connect_timeout: 5 # sec
  checkout_timeout: 5 # sec
  template: template0
  schema_search_path: "public,extensions"
```

PS. I found this one doing the opposite somewhat of the way https://gist.github.com/pricees/9630464

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help?

[Get DATABASE_URL from config hash](https://github.com/seamusabshere/database_url#get-database_url-from-config-hash)

You pass it a hash (string or symbol keys, doesn't matter) and it gives you a URL:

```
>> c = YAML.load_file('/path/to/config/database.yml')
=> {"development"=>{"adapter"=>"mysql2", "database"=>"myapp_development", "username"=>"root", "password"=>"password", "encoding"=>"utf8"}, "test"=>{"adapter"=>"mysql2", "database"=>"myapp_test", "username"=>"root", "password"=>"password", "encoding"=>"utf8"}, "production"=>{"adapter"=>"mysql2", "database"=>"myapp", "username"=>"myapp", "password"=>"XXX", "encoding"=>"utf8"}, "cucumber"=>{"adapter"=>"mysql2", "database"=>"myapp_cucumber", "username"=>"root", "password"=>"password", "encoding"=>"utf8"}}
>> DatabaseUrl.to_active_record_url c['development']
=> "mysql2://root:password@127.0.0.1/myapp_development?encoding=utf8"
```

Answer (score 1):

No - there is no built in method.

Connection handling in ActiveRecord is handled by [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionHandling`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html) which takes configurations as both hashes and URLs and merges them.

So while you can take a URL and convert it into a configuration object with:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification::ConnectionUrlResolver.new(url)
```

There is no provisions for going the other way since its not needed by the framework as it passes the configuration as a hash to to the connection adapter.

Comment: Beware of using YAML.load to get the configuration through. It does not evaluate the file using ERB so if you are using ERB to pass variables from ENV they won't be expanded. A better alternative is `Rails.configuration.database_configuration` which is how Rails loads it.